# SSL not working for some reason with restriction to HTTP1.0 requests and/or restriction some HTTP verbs

Tags: .htaccess, ssl

In my .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
#RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^POST(.*)HTTP/(0\.9|1\.0)$ [NC]
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^(delete|head|trace|track) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]
```

if I want to use

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^POST(.*)HTTP/(0\.9|1\.0)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^(delete|head|trace|track) [NC]
```

but if I am trying to use these the SSL is not working and if I am removing these two lines SSL is working properly. How I can solve this problem.

Comment: It is doing that I think because you have it set as three re-write conditions, but they're not all being met. So nothing is happen.  What are you trying to achieve with your other conditions?

Comment: @thickguru thank you, I want to restrict HTTP 1.0 requests and also  delete,head,trace,track with SSL working .

Comment: Oh wait, I think the issue is that you're not using `[OR]`. One second, will pop in an answer.

Comment: This `HTTP/0.9` in the regex is wrong since a HTTP 0.9 request simply consists of `GET /page` without any HTTP version number. See https://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/AsImplemented.html.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Can you please post an answer with description, taht will be really helpful .

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu: my comment is probably not the cause of the problem you describe in your question, so I post it as a comment and not as an answer.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich no problem still I am thankful to you .

Comment: @SteffenUllrich you may like to edit the answer to make it better, as I added the working one to make it helpful to next person who will come across  it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the issue that you're having is that it is running just the one condition and getting stuck because you're not using `[OR]`. I've also edited your first condition.

```
RewriteEngine On 

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on [OR] 
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^POST(.*)HTTP/(0\.9|1\.0)$ [NC, OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^(delete|head|trace|track) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

Make sure you clear your cache before testing this.

An edit for you to try, first force everything to HTTPs itself:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond {HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=302,L]
```

I'm not 100% sure of what you're trying to achieve with this second part, as if you want to force HTTPs on everything, then the above will do it no problem. I read in your question title restrictions, are these supposed to be restrictions? As right now they're not.

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^POST(.*)HTTP/(0\.9|1\.0)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^(delete|head|trace|track) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Working One

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on [OR] 
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^POST(.*)HTTP/(0\.9|1\.0)$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^(delete|head|trace|track) [NC,OR]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

Comment: but now the SSL is not forced, it is now optional .

Comment: I want it to be always https with those restrictions .

Comment: It is forced, because that first condition checks if HTTPs is on, if it is, then great, if it is not on, then it forces. So it takes any three of those conditions. But if you prefer, you can split those conitions so that they run seperatly, have the HTTPs as a seperate rule and then run the other two afterwards?

Comment: I am able to access that url with http and it should redirct to https.

Comment: Is it only for those pages you're trying to force HTTPs? Or everything?

Comment: HTTPS will be for every pages .

Comment: I advise that you split the rules then. I've added an edit to my answer which splits them. So it will run the forcing of HTTPs first.

Comment: Oh, brilliant! I look forward to seeing the change!

Comment: Another important part is [NC, OR] space is not allowed here, so it should be [NC,OR] the space causing 500 internal server error.

Comment: I was correct from the start lol, that it was missing the `[OR]`, but I added a space... *facepalm*. Glad I helped to get there anyway.

Comment: Have you notice comment from  Steffen Ullrich ? Can you make it better with his suggestion ?

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu: I think you can simply ignore clients which use HTTP 0.9 since the protocol was obsoleted 20 years ago. There is not even a browser today which uses HTTP/1.0 which was  the successor to HTTP 0.9. All browsers use either HTTP/1.1 or HTTP/2. This is true even for IE8.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich wow! thank you for your effort. but how I can do it in .htacess I do not know, I have learned using .htacess only from stackoverflow from https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/http2.html it seems I should use `Protocols h2 h2c http/1.1` am I correct ?

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu: you don't need a special handling for HTTP/2. If a client is doing HTTP/2 it is already doing HTTPS since browsers will only do HTTP/2 with TLS (i.e. HTTP/2).